Ctrl-Backslash to send an ASCII character
This works (Ctrl-Backslash key sends the text in question):
^VKDC::Send("BlahBlah")

This also works (Keys hit sequentially "/q" emits the ASCII char 168 namely upside down question mark ¿
::/q::{Asc 168}

I want the Ctrl-Backslash Key (VK2D) to map to sending the ASCII character 168 that is ¿
I have tried all manner of combinations but no luck.
Any ideas?
10000000000000000000000000000 thank yous!
I have tried this combinations mostly does not compile:
::^VKDC::{Asc 168}          ; Ctrl-Blackslash compiles. Does nothing
::^VKDC::{Asc 168}          ; Ctrl-Blackslash compiles. Does nothing
;^VK2D::Send, {Asc 0168}
;^VK_SCROLL::{Asc 0168}
;^VK_OEM_5::Send, {ASC 168}
;^Backslash::Send, {ASC 168}
;^::\::Send, {ASC 168}
;::^\::{ASC 168}          ; Compiles but nothing comes out
;::\::{ASC 168}           ; Funny pipe comes but only with a leading backslash
;^sc029::Send, {ASC 168}
;^sc029::Send, {Asc 168}
;^sc029::{Asc 168}
;ScrollLock::Send {Asc 168}
;^ScrollLock::{Asc 0168}
;^SC02C::Send, {Asc 0168}
;^SC02C::{Asc 0168}


Are you sure it's at 168? I see '¿' in Unicode as 191 (or hex 00BF). By the way, real ASCII goes to 127 max. this site also lists that ¿ at 191 in CP-1252

By the way, using a US-International keyboard, I can type ¿ directly: right-alt + ?

Standard ASCII defines chars up to #127. What you refer to as #168 will depend on (kinda deprecated) local encoding pages (ASCII extensions to 255 chars).
Try usind Unicode definitions instead.
This works for me, only don't forget to save the script in "unicode UTF-8-BOM" encoding. That is what AHK expects.
^\::
    send ¿
return

